# How to neglect all chars betwen a specific character set?

Tags: java, regex

I have formulated the following RegExp that I want to transform to code. But having some trouble:

"Match at least one `=`, and neglect everything up to a special character set, no matter how often these special chars occur."

Where special set could be: `()|&!`

Example, for the following, I want to neglect everything that is between `in` and `out`:

```
(in == 1'b1) | !out & (sig==1'b0)
```

The following regex will eg make a plit for groups: `==`, `) | !`:

```
\s*[=][&()!|=\s]*
```

But how can I also match the `1'b1` between in and out, which would be some kind of "match anything after one `=` up to one or more of the special chars?

Comment: I am not sure how your regex/code should work. Could you provide some examples for input data and expected output/result?

Comment: Input is the example string above. Output should be a split array with 3 groups: `in, out, sig`. Thus, everything between these "variables" should be negelected.

Comment: What output would be generated for `(in1 == 1'b1) | 2out)`? Can words contain numbers, or even start with them?

Comment: good point. Yes, words might also start, contain or end with numbers like `2out` `out2`.

Comment: So if I assume correctly tokens in your input `(in == 1'b1) | !out & (sig==1'b0)` are `in` `1'b1` `out` `sig` `1'b0`, but you only want to return those that contain at least one letter and no special characters like `'`. I am not sure if you would like to also return something like `123`, or can we assume that this kind of token will never be used in input data?

Comment: Almost. I don' t want eg `1'b1` to be a token. In this example I'd like to have nothing that is contained between `in` and `out`. But you're correct, I don't want to return something `like` 123, I can assume the tokens I want consist at least of one word character like `123a` or  `a123` or `a123a`. Further, if I write `(in == 12) | !out` I still only want to return `in` and `out`.

Comment: `contained between "in" and "out"` Is there possibility that there will be few `in` and `out`s in your input data? Like `(in1 == 1'b1) |(in == 1'b1) | !out & (sig==1'b0) | !1out2 & (sig==1'b0)`?

Comment: according to your example, I'd expect the following array: `in1, in, out, sig, 1out2, sig`

Comment: What came up with the following regex so far: `\s*[&()!|=][&()!|=\s].*?[^\&()!|=]*([&()!|][&()!|\s]*)`, but it is kind of ugly, and does for example not take the first `(` from my teststring. But it's probably close...?

Comment: OK, try: `\s*[&()!|=\s].*?[^\&()!|=]*([&()!|][&()!|\s]*)`, could you spot any failures in this string? Or maybe you have a better or optimized regex? At least this expression seems to work using test at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't have to be one regex then you can try this way

```
String data = "(in1 == 1'b1) |(in == 1'b1) | !out & (sig==1'b0) | !1out2 & (sig==1'b0)";
// I will try to split on every special character and space
String[] allTokens = data.split("[=()&|!\\s]+");
// but this will produce
// [, in1, 1'b1, in, 1'b1, out, sig, 1'b0, 1out2, sig, 1'b0]

// so I will try to filter tokens that are not only digits and letters
// with at least one letter
List<String> correctTokens = new ArrayList<>();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]");
//(?=.*[a-zA-Z]) will return true if data will contain at least one letter
//and will contain only letters a-zA-Z and digits 0-9
for (String s : allTokens) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches()) {
        correctTokens.add(s);
    }
}
System.out.println(correctTokens);
```

output:

```
[in1, in, out, sig, 1out2, sig]
```